# Searching Text For an Integer and a String (EX: searching for "X pizzas")

Tags: python, string, search

I'm currently working on a project that involves reading in a large set of strings (its a report in pdf form) and scanning it for some specific substrings. Specifically I am searching for "X COAs" where X can be any integer. Is there any way to search for this specifically? I've yet to find a workaround using simple string manipulation.

Here's the current code:
Note that pdfpath is just the directory where the pdf is stored.

```
import pdfminer
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

text = extract_text(pdfpath)
linebyline = text.splitlines()
for x in linebyline:
#         print(x)
    if ((" COAs") in x):
        numCOAs = x
        break
    else:
        numCOAs = "ERROR: NO COA NUMBER FOUND"
print(f"There are {numCOAs}")
```

I've mostly done research on other threads on how to solve this issue but I haven't found anyone with the exact same situation as this one. I've tried searching for "@ COAs" but that didn't work either. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can use regular expression [`(\d+)\s+COAs`](https://regex101.com/r/8R6rFN/1). `numCOAs = m.group(1) if (m := re.search(r"(\d+)\s+COAs", text)) else "ERROR"`. Imports: [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: @OlvinRoght I hadn't thought of using regex but this was absolutely the solution I'm looking for! Thank you so much.